# Using a vector Android NDK - Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, stl, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I've read all the other posts involving STL libraries and the Android NDK with Eclipse, but I am still having this problem in my JNI file:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> test;
test.push_back("hello");
std::vector<std::string>::size_type h = 0;
unsigned int t = 0;
std::string blah = test.at(h);
std::string hell = test.at(t);
```

`at()` is syntax highlighted in both instances with the following error message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
stlpmtx_std::basic_string<char,stlpmtx_std::char_traits<char>,stlpmtx_std::allocator<char>> & at(?)
const stlpmtx_std::basic_string<char,stlpmtx_std::char_traits<char>,stlpmtx_std::allocator<char>> & at(?)
'
```

Nothing else is highlighted.  The library builds fine. The same result with a built in data type, such as `vector<int>`.

With:

```
int h = 0;
memcpy(ar, res, h);
```

I get memcpy highlighted with the following message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void * memcpy(void *, const void *, ?)
'
```

Here is Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

and Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# *** Remember: Change -O0 into -O2 in add-applications.mk ***

LOCAL_MODULE    := soundtouch
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := soundtouch-jni.cpp soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/AAFilter.cpp  soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp \
                soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/FIRFilter.cpp soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/cpu_detect_x86.cpp \
                soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/RateTransposer.cpp soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/SoundTouch.cpp \
                soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/TDStretch.cpp soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/BPMDetect.cpp soundtouch/source/SoundTouch/PeakFinder.cpp

# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lgcc 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/soundtouch/include
# --whole-archive -lgcc 
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
#LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid
# don't export all symbols
# added "-marm" switch to use arm instruction set instead of thumb for improved calculation performance.
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -I soundtouch/source/../include -D ST_NO_EXCEPTION_HANDLING -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -marm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My *C++ General - Paths and Symbols* includes:

```
D:\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
D:\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
D:\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-8\arch-arm\usr\include
```

How can I have these correct statements not generate an error for the purposes of syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

[c++ eclipse wrong error interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354559/c-eclipse-wrong-error-interpretation)

Looks like an Eclipse CDT bug. Report it?

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/support.php

Comment: Ack, (facepalm)...Eclipse